# How To Integrate SCORM 2.4 With AS3?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, scorm, scorm2004

I have a project which demands integration of AS3 learning game and a LMS...

Right now I've been using this AS3 class from [pipwerks.com](http://pipwerks.com) but i was not able to get access to further integration like a certain activity and grading... (cmi.objectives)

if someone familiar with this class - there is a way to call in the cmi.objectives?

And for those who develop Flash games with SCORM integration -

how can i achieve the best integration?

do you familiar with better ways to combine SCORM and AS3?

I know there is JS classes as well - but how can i use them with AS3?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome to **S.O**. What is your real question? Imagine no-one knows or cares for SCORM... Is your question "how to communicate between an AS3 function and a JS function"? Would that help you get somewhere with helping yourself? Now imagine someone here knows SCORM... Do you have a part of code your struggling with? How can an Answerer recreate your problem? Show some code that illustrates your intergration issue. Did you try to google for tutorials & articles about AS3/JS function inter-communication?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the topic SCORM API can bi triggered by JS calles.

Once I've implemented AS3 <-> SCORM connector, it was based on AS3 <-> JS communication. In AS3 one can call JS with the help of ExternalInterface. Example call to API:

`ExternalInterface.call("api.LMSGetValue","cmi.core.lesson_location");`

You only need to keep attention to the initialization process (to be sure init methods are called) to get any reposnse to AS3 from JS.

Answer (score 0):

> i was not able to get access to further integration like a certain activity and grading... (cmi.objectives)
>
> if someone familiar with this class - there is a way to call in the cmi.objectives?

The [pipwerks SCORM wrapper](https://github.com/pipwerks/scorm-api-wrapper) supports your scenario. It uses ExternalInterface, coupled with a JavaScript file, to get/set any SCORM RTE calls, e.g. `scorm.set("cmi.objectives.1.score.raw", 98)`. All [SCORM RTE calls](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/) are supported by the pipwerks wrappers (JS, AS2, and AS3).

If your `cmi.objectives` call is not working, it's probably either a typo in your code, or an incompatibility on the LMS end -- not all LMSs support the full SCORM RTE data set.